# Get MySQL column names in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Can someone please help me how to get my MySQL column names out in my while loop?
My code goes like this:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "MySQL failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $get_date = $_GET['date'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE form_date = '$get_date'");
    $col = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $col[] = $row['year'];
        $col[] = $row['month'];
        $col[] = $row['day'];
        $col[] = $row['weekday'];
        $col[] = $row['form_date'];
        $col[] = $row['name'];
        $col[] = $row['count'];
        $col[] = $row['lang'];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($col);
    echo "</pre>";
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "Please set a date value in URL parameter ?date=[YYYY-MM-DD]";
}
```

My returned array then looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 01
    [3] => Wednesday
    [4] => 2014-01-01
    [5] => Michael K
    [6] => 41
    [7] => SE
    [8] => 2014
    [9] => 01
    [10] => 01
    [11] => Wednesday
    [12] => 2014-01-01
    [13] => Nicklas S
    [14] => 40
    [15] => DK
    [16] => 2014
    [17] => 01
    [18] => 01
    [19] => Wednesday
    [20] => 2014-01-01
    [21] => Jesper S
    [22] => 5
    [23] => SE
)
```

However I would like my array to get returned like this:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2014
    [day] => 01
    [month] => 01
    [weekday] => Wednesday
    [form_date] => 2014-01-01
    [name] => Michael K
    [count] => 41
    [lang] => SE
    [year] => 2014
    [month] => 01
    [day] => 01
    [weekday] => Wednesday
    [form_date] => 2014-01-01
    [name] => Nicklas S
    [count] => 40
    [lang] => DK
    [year] => 2014
    [month] => 01
    [day] => 01
    [weekday] => Wednesday
    [form_date] => 2014-01-01
    [name] => Jesper S
    [count] => 5
    [lang] => SE
)
```

So the keys in my array matches the column names I have in my database.
I just can't seem to wrap my head around how I do this. Can someone help? :-)

Comment: You can't have an array like that.  It's impossible.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes you can, that's an associative array in PHP

Comment: @mituw16 associative arrays are fine, but not with duplicate keys.

Comment: @mituw16: It's littered with duplicate keys.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't notice that. Was just commenting that associative arrays are possible in PHP

Comment: @mituw16: My original comment was about the duplicate keys though.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I just read it wrong, your original comment is spot on :)

Comment: Most answers recommends to use [**mysqli_fetch_assoc**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) but this isn't necessary since `mysqli_fetch_array` returns both arrays (numeric and associative)

Comment: As  @Rocket Hazmat said, what you're currently trying to do is impossible. How do you expect to retrieve a value from an array if more than one value has the same key??  Store each result set in its own array, then store than array in an array that stores all sets. You can then loop through that master array to get the sub arrays which hold all the values you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$col = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $col[] = $row['year'];
    $col[] = $row['month'];
    $col[] = $row['day'];
    $col[] = $row['weekday'];
    $col[] = $row['form_date'];
    $col[] = $row['name'];
    $col[] = $row['count'];
    $col[] = $row['lang'];
}
```

to

```
$col = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $col[] = $row;
}

print_r($col);
```

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) has second argument. This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who reacted this quickly! This was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Check this solution, it won't produce duplicate keys as others suggested because it will be fetched as assoc array. and stored in $col array.

Comment: @Robert not that I care about a checkmark on a question like this, but comments like "accept this answer" come off as very 'rep-farm-ish'. A good answer will earn the mark without advertising it

Comment: I don't advertise my answer I just write him to check it because I think it will fit his needs. I don't need checkmark I don't write answers to get one I write ones to help people.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) which fetches results as an associative array (column => value).

Then try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an associative array like this because it will have duplicate key indices, which is not allowed. I suggest you work with a restructured array to have each "group" of keys as a nested array.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mysql_assoc_array()` instead of `mysq_fetch_array()`